# Custom Content- Predefined image selection

Tags: media, files

I am trying to create a custom content type that allows the user to select PREDEFINED images. This means the user WILL NOT have the option to upload image. I have seen people use the media module, but one I don't want the user to upload image and two I want to provide a selection option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Select with Style](https://drupal.org/project/select_with_style) module. More info go through the documentation of this module.

Or if it not suits as your requirement try [jQuery Image Select](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-image-select/3946862?ref=jqueryrain) with customization.